# How to download a file that I have chosen from Google Picker API?

Tags: javascript, php, google-picker

I am implementing the Google Picker in a PHP site. I am able to get the file id from the Google Picker API and also I can download the file using JavaScript. Following is my callback function called in setCallback(pickerCallback) function.

```
function pickerCallback(data) {
    if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
      document.getElementById('googleFileId').value = fileId;
      var name = data.docs[0].name;
      var url = data.docs[0].url;
      var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + fileId);
      request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
      request.addEventListener('load', function() {
          var item = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
          window.open(item.webContentLink,"_self"); //Download file in Client Side 
      });
      request.send();
    }
    var message = 'File ID of choosen file : ' + fileId;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
}
```

I can pass the file id to PHP, but to download the file I have to authenticate again. Can any one help in how to proceed with file download in PHP ?

There is a Manage Downloads help in Google Developers page but it is not working for me https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads.

Found a question similar to this one but no answers to how to download the file in backend [Download file right after picked file from google picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824421/download-file-right-after-picked-file-from-google-picker).

Comment: If you have the file id, why can't you use [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) to get the `downloadUrl` and use that to download the file?

Comment: When I use files.get it returns a 404 file not found as I think I have to authenticate again to access the file info (i.e get downloadUrl). To authenticate I have to create the authurl and ask the user to authenticate right? Which makes the  authentication twice one through Google Picker and another to download. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you're getting a 404 error, I think you don't have the proper permissions to access that file. Check to make sure you do.

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how to download the file in PHP? As I am totally confused on how to do it. Can you provide me the steps to be followed after getting the fileId from Google Picker and before getting file metadata in PHP as given in [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get). I am trying to implement this in localhost will that be a problem ? @Andy

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a callback for the pick action. Take a look at my implementation:

```js
    var buildPicker = function(parentId) {

      var pickerCallback = function(data) {
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] === google.picker.Action.PICKED && data.viewToken[0] !== 'upload') {
          var docs = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS];
          for (var d = 0; d < docs.length; d++) {
            downloadFile(docs[d].id);
          }
        }
      };

      GAuth.getToken().then(function(token) {
        var picker = new $window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setParent(parentId))
          .addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setParent(parentId).setIncludeFolders(true))
          .setDeveloperKey(apiKey)
          .setOAuthToken(token.access_token)
          .setCallback(pickerCallback);

        picker.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED);
        picker.build().setVisible(true);
      });



    };

    var downloadFile = function(fileId) {

      getFile(fileId).then(function(file) {
        var downloadUrl;
        if (angular.isDefined(file.exportLinks)) {
          downloadUrl = file.exportLinks['application/pdf'];
        } else {
          downloadUrl = file.webContentLink;
        }
        var $idown;
        var makeiFrame = function(url) {
          if ($idown) {
            $idown.attr('src', url);
          } else {
            $idown = $('<iframe>', {
              id: 'idown',
              src: url
            }).hide().appendTo('body');
          }
        };
        makeiFrame(downloadUrl);
      });
    };


     // Implemented with https://github.com/maximepvrt/angular-google-gapi. But any other implementation will be fine as well
    var getFile = function(fileId) {
      var parameters = {
        'fileId': fileId
      };
      return GApi.executeAuth('drive', 'files.get', parameters);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```